# Setting Up GUI Object to Switch between Pages [android]

Tags: android, user-interface

In an effort to become better at android, my new learning project is creating a custom GUI object to switch between "pages". An example would be using the object for a social network to switch between a profile page, a friends page, and a messages page.

I want this object visible on screen at all times while it's running

On to my question now:

How do I handle the pages so that the object only loads once and is always visible in between loading different pages?

I was going to have each page as its own activity but I'm afraid if when a page gets selected and the new activity is loaded, my object would first disappear with the old activity and then reappear with the new activity. Not only does using multiple activities sound completely wrong to me is also seems very inefficient to have the object reload each time a new page is selected.

This makes me think that each page doesn't need to be a new activity, maybe just load a new layout while keeping the object in the front or something like that I'm not sure.

I've never done anything with multiple "pages" so I apologize if this is a dumb question

Comment: Just remember that the slowest thing you can do on a mobile processor is to ask for more memory.

Comment: thanks for the tip! also @Robusto are you referring to using multiple layouts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewPager was built for this type of thing. Try putting your layouts in here and they can be horizontally swiped.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

Comment: Thanks! While I don't care about the horizontal swipe part the ViewPager is what I was looking for. I hate using apps like news apps that you try to read text vertically and it moves slightly horizontal when swiping vertically and can accidentally switch views *cough cough* google reader *cough*